# Fetch and Show Download For PDF File from Database in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having a record of username and pdfile file stored in the database, i want to show list of records with a download option for that pdf file path, i tried some of the code , but still it didnt resolve my issue. By Using the below code, it is showing download option but getting console error

> Not Allowed to load local resource

If anyone has anyother idea , how to do it in a better way

```
public ActionResult ViewFromDb()
        {
            ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

            var list = db.MeetingDetails.ToList();
            list.ForEach(x => {
                x.filepath = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/App_Data/File" + x.filepath));
            });
            return View(list);
        }
```

```
@model IEnumerable<ReportManagement.Models.MeetingDetail>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ViewFromDb";
}

<h2>ViewFromDb</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.filepath)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
        </td>

        <td>
           <a href="@(item.filepath)">Download</a>
        </td>


    </tr>
}
</table>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ReportManagement.Models
{
    public class MeetingDetail
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public string filepath { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public HttpPostedFileBase file { get; set; }
    }
}
```

After suggestion i tried one more thing to do, but in that i am not sure how to show that in view

```
 //public ActionResult ViewFromDb()
        //{
        //    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        //    MeetingDetail ms = new MeetingDetail();
        //    DirectoryInfo dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(ms.filepath);
        //    FileInfo[] files = dirinfo.GetFiles("*.*");
        //    List<string> lst = new List<string>(files.Length);
        //    foreach(var item in files)
        //    {
        //        lst.Add(item.Name);
        //    }
        //    return View(lst);
        //}

        //public ActionResult DownloadFromDb(string filename)
        //{
        //    MeetingDetail ms = new MeetingDetail();
        //    if (Path.GetExtension(ms.filepath) == ".pdf")
        //    {
        //        string fullpath = Path.Combine(ms.filepath, filename);
        //        return File(fullpath, "application/pdf");
        //    }
        //    else
        //        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);

        //}


//@{
  //  ViewBag.Title = "ViewFiles";
//}

//<h2>ViewFiles</h2>

//@foreach(var item in ViewData.Model)
//{
    @Html.ActionLink((model=>item.Filepath)item, "DownloadFile", new { filename //= item });

//}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you use the App_Data folder, and one of the purposes around this folder is that its content is not accessible from web, but from web app. That is why databases etc is put there. Stuff that should not be accessible from web.

Try creating another folder (like /Content) and put the files there.

If the files does not exist in physical form, but as bytes in database or blob storage, you must create an endpoint that works as a proxy between the client and the data storage. Like this:
[ASP.NET MVC: FileStreamResult returning too many bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277620/asp-net-mvc-filestreamresult-returning-too-many-bytes)

Comment: When i am viewing in solution explorer, the files are showing there, but not in the project, and i am saving only the path of files in database

Comment: I tried creating a folder under content but still getting the same issue "Not allowed to load local resources"

Comment: Server.MapPath will give you the physical drive on server and that is not something the web client knows about.

Comment: What is the solution then

Comment: If your files exists as files in the App_Data folder, that may be an ok place to keep them. Either way, App_Data, database bytes or blob storage, you can create an Action in a Controller (like /Home/MeetingFile) that accepts an ID that is the name of the file, then you read the file byte content from App_Data (by using a stream and Server.MapPath) and return the bytes in your new MeetingFile Action. Or get bytes from database or bytes from blob storage and return in the Action. Either way, the Action returns bytes, you will need another type of Action and a Content-Type.

Comment: Please go through my edit once, i tried to do like u said, but i was getting an issue there

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code:

`x.filepath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/File" + x.filepath+".pdf");`

Comment: I tried your code, but still getting the same issue, even i created a different folder other that app_data, i created a folder under content, but still getting the same issue

Comment: create folder another drives.and change access Folder to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Actually IIS server prevents taking any file from ~/App_Data/ for security purpose as I know. So we need to return file as FileStream. This piece of code worked for me.

```
var fileSavePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/FilePath/" + DocPath));
 return File(new FileStream(fileSavePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), "application/pdf");
```

Comment: Where do u want me to write this code , according to my code

Comment: I've used Ajax call in download button, which sends id from hidden column in table to action and then get the file path and return the file as FileStream.

Comment: [Unable to access images stored inside AppData folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928301/unable-to-access-images-stored-inside-my-app-data-folder)
this solution may help you. similar problem I guess.